# Incompatible @typescript-eslint non-null-assertion rules?

Tags: typescript, eslint, typescript-eslint

I have this code:

```js
const payload: Payload = {
  id: getSyncValue(this.id$) as string,
  changes: { ... }
};
```

where `getSyncValue(this.id$)` is of type `string | null`.
In the execution context, I know that `getSyncValue(this.id$)` is not null.
That is why I use the `as` cast to explicitly tell Typescript that it is a `string`.

Playing with `@typescript-eslint` and its rules,

The [`non-nullable-type-assertion-style`](https://typescript-eslint.io/rules/non-nullable-type-assertion-style/) rule tells me that I should use the `!` non-null assertion operator to be more concise:

```js
const payload: Payload = {
  id: getSyncValue(this.id$)!,
  changes: { ... }
};
```

But when I use it, the [`no-non-null-assertion`](https://typescript-eslint.io/rules/no-non-null-assertion/) rule tells me that the `!` operator is forbidden.

So I have the impression that these rules are incompatible?
What confuses me is that [they are both activated in the `plugin:@typescript-eslint/all` config](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/main/packages/eslint-plugin/src/configs/all.ts)
and I am wondering how can developers deal with it?

Comment: Not type-asserting > `!` > `as (not null)`. Ideally the compiler should also know it's not null at that point, but if you really can't make that happen then override the rule.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For your use case, I'd say disable `no-non-null-assertion`.

Also, [the documentation](https://typescript-eslint.io/linting/configs/#all) states that it's not recommended to extend from `all`, as many rules conflict with each other. Maybe extend from `recommended` or `recommended-type-checked`